# generating function of $(1/n)a_n$ in terms of the generating function of $a_n$

Tags: generating-functions

I have the generating function of $a_n$, $A(z)$, and I want to find the generating function of $(1/n)a_n$ in terms of the generating function of $a_n$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try integration of the generating function.

Comment: My backgrounds is on engineering, would you please explain more or refer me to a document?

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer.

Comment: By the way, you can reverse this.  If $A(z)$ is the generating function of the sequence $\{a_n\}$, then $z A^\prime(z)$ is the generating function of the sequence $\{ n a_n \}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given
\begin{align*}
A(z) & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{n}\\
A(z)-a_0 & =a_1z+a_2z^2+\dotsb + a_nz^n +\dotsb\\
\frac{A(z)-a_0}{z} & =a_1+a_2z^1+\dotsb + a_nz^{n-1} +\dotsb\\
\int \frac{A(z)-a_0}{z} \, dz & =a_1z+\frac{a_2}{2}z^2+\dotsb + \frac{a_n}{n}z^n +\dotsb.
\end{align*}

Thus the generating function is 
$$\int \frac{A(z)-a_0}{z} \, dz$$

Comment: We must assume $a_0=0$ in order to make sense of this problem. Or perhaps we can assume that by $a_n/n$ we mean the sequence whose zeroth term is anything (can be adjusted by the arbitrary constant for your integral) and the rest given by $a_n/n$.